# laravel use SSH in controller

Tags: laravel, ssh, laravelcollective

Im trying to use SSH:: command in my controller but I'm facing error:

```
Class 'SSH' not found
```

my controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Session;
use DB;
use SSH;
```

and call action:

```
SSH::run(
            array(
                'cd /var/www/laravel',
                'node accept.js '
            )
        );
```

so where the problem could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to follow the [installation guide](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/ssh#installation) of Laravel SSH package:

**1. Install it via Composer:**

Add this to your `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
  "laravelcollective/remote": "~5.0"
}
```

Then run `composer update`.

**2. Add new provider to the providers array of `config/app.php`:**

```
'providers' => [
  // ...
  'Collective\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider',
  // ...
],
```

**3. Add two class aliases to the aliases array of `config/app.php`:**

```
'aliases' => [
  // ...
  'SSH' => 'Collective\Remote\RemoteFacade',
  // ...
],
```

Comment: now I see error "Remote connection [] not defined."

Comment: that is another error, you should create another question with detailed description.